# How to display -- in itemize to descripe command-line options

Tags: itemize

My problem is that `--` is not displaying as it does when you put in an `itemize` environment. Instead, it's displayed as one long line which is like two dash worth length line.

I have tried `\textendash`, but nothing worked.

**My LaTeX file looks like**

```
\begin{itemize}
\item '--abc' abcdefghijklmn
\item '--def' aerfoaweijfoae
\end{itemize}
```

I would like to make this document look like:

```
 ・ '--abc' abcdefghijklmn
 ・ '--def' aerfoaweijfoae
```

Comment: try this: -{}- ?

Comment: Just a wild guess: are you trying to describe command line parameters? Then `\verb|--abc|` ?

Comment: yes I am trying to display --help or --something from command line

Comment: I will try \verb|--abc| now and let you know !

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU !
YOU ARE MY HERO !  THANK YOU SO SO MUCH !!!

Comment: I edited the title a bit to make this question easier to search for. Feel free to change it back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

Tex automatically combines -- to a longer dash. As this is not desired when typesetting command line options, you could use the `\verb|...|` command (or any other source code typesetting package). This has also the advantage that the font is automatically switched to a computerish-looking typewriter font.

My personal preference however would be to use a `description` environment instead of `itemize`. This does not allow direct usage of `\verb||`, but one can use `\usepackage[Q=yes]{examplep}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[Q=yes]{examplep}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize} 
    \item \verb|--abc| abcdefghijklmn 
    \item \verb|--abc| aerfoaweijfoae 
\end{itemize}

\begin{description}
    \item[\Q{--abc}] abcdefghijklmn 
    \item[\Q{--abc}] abcdefghijklmn 
\end{description}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Nyanko Good to hear seemed to help you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see How do you accept an answer?). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.